# Good resources explaining Domain Controllers and Active Directory

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain-controller

I'm coming from a mainly Linux background, and need to get to grips with the Windows environment: Active Directory, Domain Controllers etc. Can anyone recommend some good resources for an absoloute beginner on these subjects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try Technet at microsoft.com, and do a search on Active Directory to get some good basics.  I also found the [Active Directory](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520601) book by O'Reilly very useful early in my Windows administration career.

Comment: +1 for the Active Directory book, I still use it occasionally today.

Answer (score 1):

You can get started right from Microsoft:

https://www.microsoft.com/events/series/adaug.aspx

Microsoft's Technet forums are also a great place for quesions - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/categories

Other then those AD has gone through a few big improvements since Windows 2000, I would suggest any AD/Windows server books based around what your AD is built for (2000,2003,2003R2,2008,2008R2).

Comment: +1 for the virtual labs

Answer (score 1):

Also I think it depends on if you want book knowledge or practical knowledge.  Here are some good resources you might not find on just googling around.  You'll notice a lot of them are from technet, but technet I find generally too large for browsing.

Also if you are familiar with linux ldap - AD will come a lot easier to you.  A good place to start might be learning about the different roles of AD.

AD
AD Blog: [blogs.technet.com/b/ad/](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/)

AD powershell blog: [blogs.msdn.com/b/adpowershell/](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adpowershell/)

AD services team: [blogs.technet.com/b/askds/](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/)

Brian Desmond: [briandesmond.com/](http://briandesmond.com/)

AD tools: [blog.joeware.net/](http://blog.joeware.net/)

Jose Barretto: [blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/](http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/)

Open a socket: [www.open-a-socket.com/](http://www.open-a-socket.com/)

The life of Brian: [msmvps.com/blogs/ad/default.aspx](http://msmvps.com/blogs/ad/default.aspx)

Comment: Very comprehensive list. Hope you don't mind me making your links active for you.